# Angular Jasmine Test: SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS when using setTimeout

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to write a unit test for a components in my App. It's a very simple component called TroubleShootingPage that is only supposed to show a help page, if someone has trouble somewhere in the rest of my app.

All tests are passing, but in the output in Karma I see a hint: **SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS**:

[image: My Karma Output]

The test that supposedly has no expectations is dealing with the function `getTroubleShootingPage()` in my TroubleShootingPage Component, which looks like this:

```
export interface Entry<T> {
    sys: Sys;
    fields: T;
    toPlainObject(): object;
    update(): Promise<Entry<T>>;
}

troubleShootingPage: Entry<any>;

constructor(private contentfulService: ContentfulService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getTroubleShootingPage("en-US")
}

getTroubleShootingPage(locale: string) {
    this.contentfulService.getTroubleShootingPage(locale).then(page => {
      this.troubleShootingPage = page;
      ...
  }
}
```

As you can see, the content/text of the troubleshooting page has to be loaded from the contentfulService and there it is loaded from an API (Contentful) depending on the user's language. So I only want to secure that the function gets called and that the returned input from the contentfulService gets correctly assigned to the variable `this.troubleShootingPage`.

The test looks like this:

```
describe('TroubleshootingPageComponent', () => {
    let component: TroubleshootingPageComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<TroubleshootingPageComponent>;
    
    let contentfulServiceStub: Partial<ContentfulService> = {
        getTroubleShootingPage: () => {
            return new Promise<Entry<any>>(() => {
                return troubleShootingPageMock;
            });
        }
    };

    let troubleShootingPageMock: Entry<any>;
    troubleShootingPageMock = {
        fields: {
            description: "Please read here for further help:",
            mainText: {},
            textCancelButton: "Quit",
            textConfirmButton: "Continue",
            title: "Need Help?"
        },
        toPlainObject() {
            return null;
        },
        update() {
            return null;
        },
        sys: {
            type: "",
            id: "string",
            createdAt: "string",
            updatedAt: "string",
            locale: "string",
            contentType: {
                sys: null
            },
        },
    };

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [],
            declarations: [TroubleshootingPageComponent],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
            providers: [{ provide: ContentfulService, useValue: contentfulServiceStub }]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TroubleshootingPageComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

   it('should get the troubleShootingPage form Contentful', () => {
        component.getTroubleShootingPage("en-GB");
        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(component.troubleShootingPage).toEqual(troubleShootingPageMock.fields);
        }, 1000)
    });

    // I also tried:
    // it('should get the troubleShootingPage form Contentful', (done) => {
    //     component.getTroubleShootingPage("en-GB");
    //     setTimeout(() => {
    //         expect(component.troubleShootingPage).toEqual(troubleShootingPageMock.fields);
    //         done();
    //     }, 1000)
    // });
});
```

I added a timeout with `setTimeout()` because without it `component.troubleShootingPage` was always `undefined`, because the test went to the `ecpect()` statement, before the Promise in the getTroubleShootingPage() function was resolved:

```
it('should get the troubleShootingPage form Contentful', () => {
            component.getTroubleShootingPage("en-GB");
            expect(component.troubleShootingPage).toEqual(troubleShootingPageMock.fields);            
});
```

-> this fails, because `component.troubleShootingPage` is `undefined`.

How could I solve this, any ideas?

Comment: To have possibility to await the result in the test from `component.getTroubleShootingPage("en-GB");` the `component.getTroubleShootingPage` function needs to return its promise. (You need to add a `return` before the `this.contentfulService.getTroubleShootingPage(locale).then(page => {` line.) If we have that in the test, we are able to use `await` or `then` to check the resolved result. I think for this approach also `async` needs to be added to the test case in `it` like this: `it('should get the troubleShootingPage form Contentful', async () => {`.

Comment: In Angular 11 it's now `waitForAsync`, but what Milan said is accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok thanks for the comments, the hint with making the function return the promise was the necessary part:

in the component I made one function for only returning the promise:

```
 getTroubleShootingPage(locale: string) {
    this.getTroubleShootingPageFromService(locale).then(page => {
      this.troubleShootingPage = page;
   })
}

getTroubleShootingPageFromService(locale: string) {
    return this.contentfulService.getTroubleShootingPage(locale);
}
```

And in my test I have now this, which works fine:

```
it('should get the troubleShootingPage form Contentful', async () => {
        spyOn(contentfulServiceStub, 'getTroubleShootingPage').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(troubleShootingPageMock))
        await component.getTroubleShootingPage("en-US");
        expect(component.troubleShootingPage).toEqual(troubleShootingPageMock);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am doing an Angular Testing course by Joseph Eames on Pluralsight.  I posted a question about this there, googling in the meantime to see if I could solve it.

The code under test does not use async / await, here it is.  The test follows.

In the course, fakeAsync() and its associated tick() or flush() methods are more apt answers.  The reason is if other tests are written to call this same function, then your 1s time will multiply for each test.  Each test using the method will delay your code by 1 second.

Check out how to use fakeAsync(), and with it tick() or flush().

Part of Mr. Eames lesson at this point includes a (done) parameter in the anonymous function after it('should call update ...), (done) => { ... and then call done() in the setTimeout after the expect.

This cleared the issue, though the reason for inserting (done) and later done() is for a different reason.

Not sure this applies in an async / await scenario but try it.  It may be simpler.

```
    import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';
import { time } from 'console';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-detail.component.css']
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() hero: Hero;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private heroService: HeroService,
    private location: Location
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHero();
  }

  getHero(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.heroService.getHero(id)
      .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }

  save(): void {
    debounce(() => {
      this.heroService.updateHero(this.hero)
        .subscribe(() => this.goBack());
    }, 250, false)();
  }
}

function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
  var timeout;
  return function () {
    var context = this, args = arguments;
    var later = function () {
      timeout = null;
      if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
    };
    var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
    if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
  }
};
```

And here is the test:

```
    import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing"
import { HeroDetailComponent } from "./hero-detail.component"
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";
import { HeroService } from "../hero.service";
import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { of } from "rxjs";
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

describe('HeroDetailComponent', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeroDetailComponent>;
    let mockActivatedRoute, mockHeroService, mockLocation;
    beforeEach(() => {
        mockActivatedRoute = {
            snapshot: { paramMap: { get: () => { return '3'; } } }
        }
        mockHeroService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['getHero', 'updateHero']);
        mockLocation = jasmine.createSpyObj(['back']);

        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [FormsModule],
            declarations: [HeroDetailComponent],
            providers: [
                { provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: mockActivatedRoute },
                { provide: HeroService, useValue: mockHeroService },
                { provide: Location, useValue: mockLocation }
            ]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeroDetailComponent);
        mockHeroService.getHero.and.returnValue(of({ id: 3, name: 'Superman', strength: 100 }))
    });
    it('should render the hero name in a h2 tag', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('h2').textContent).toContain('SUPERMAN');
    })

    it('should call updateHero when save is called', (done) => {
        mockHeroService.updateHero.and.returnValue(of({}));
        fixture.detectChanges();

        fixture.componentInstance.save();

        setTimeout(() => {
            expect(mockHeroService.updateHero).toHaveBeenCalled();
            done();
        }, 300);
    })
})
```